# Find the selected radio button in a list of <label> using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to loop through all the `label` items in a `div`. I mean there are a bunch of unknown number of label tags which inturn have radio button. Using **Selenium WebDriver**. I need to find the selected `radio button`. There are two things here:

1. I need to find the number of radio elements
2. I need to find the selected radio element

For example

```html
<div class="controls">
 <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" value="0" name="PlaceOfResidence"/>
 Urban           
 </label>
 <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="PlaceOfResidence"/>
 Suburb           
 </label>
 <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="PlaceOfResidence"/>
 Rural           
 </label>
 <label class="radio inline">
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="PlaceOfResidence"/>
 Not Available           
 </label>
</div>
```

Here is what I've tried

```
private String isRadioButtonSelected2(String name){
    List<WebElement> webEl = this.getWrappedDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name = '"+name+"']/parent::label")); //and @value='"+value+"']"));
    String selectedValue = "";
    for(WebElement element: webEl){
        Boolean selectedRadio = element.isSelected();
        if(selectedRadio){
            selectedValue =this.getWrappedDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @name = '"+name+"']/parent::label")).getText();

            log("&&&&&&&&&&"+selectedValue);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    return selectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `xpath` to find all radio buttons you can find it just simply using `By.name` which is much faster than `xpath`. Try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> radioButtons = this.getWrappedDriver().findElements(By.name("PlaceOfResidence")); 
int size = radioButtons.size();
// This is the count of total radio button

for(WebElement radio : radioButtons) 
 {
  If(radio.isSelected())
   {
     String  selectedValue =radio.findElement(By.xpath("./parent::label")).getText();
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 1):

//This will give the number of radio elements

`List<WebElement> radioButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[type=radio]"));
int size = = radioButtons.size();`

// Iterate the above element and use isSelected() method to identify the selected radio elements

Hope this clarify

Comment: That worked! I Iterated over the size and used isSelected()